# Forward VNC data from remote pc to server to avoid multiple connections into the remote pc

Tags: vnc, x11vnc

I have a remote pc under a 4G router and in the other hand a server with optical fiber. Both run on linux. What I want to achieve is to share the display of the remote pc but avoiding all my clients connecting into it. Instead of that, I want my clients to connect into the server and only the server to connect into the remote pc to retrieve the VNC data for them. This way I can share the monitor of the remote pc while saving 4G data avoiding duplicated connections into it.

To do this I supose I need a VNC server in the remote pc (already set up with x11vnc) and a sort of VNC client/server combination in the server machine that connects to the remote pc and pulls data from it continously and it's ready to serve it to whoever requests it.

I have done some googling and I have found projects like vcnproxy, uvncrepeater, vnc_reflector and some others, but most of them seem like old/abandoned/personal projects and/or with limited support for rfb protocols or authentication modes. On top of that, I don't know if these software projects save me the extra connections to the remote pc, or they only sit in the middle acting as an standard http proxy server, forwarding all the users' requests to the remote pc.

So before trying all of them, I would like to know if they fit my needs or which one can fit them. Or maybe there is a much easier way to do it and I'm wasting my time in this way. So here is where I ask for your help.

As extra info, my clients are going to be noVNC clients that will connect to the VNC server running in the server machine through websockify. I don't know if this changes anything but... Also, I have full control of the firewalls in both sides, remote & server.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the server machine: `x11vnc -reflect remote.pc.ip.address:port`

In the remote pc: `x11vnc` with your standard options

Now, duplicate connections will be made into the server machine, and the remote pc will have only one continous connection, the server one.